# Close the application after 10 minutes of inactivity without security enabled (offline application)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have the requirement to close the application after 10 minutes if the user has not interacted with the application.

All the questions about this are related to the session time out, the problem here is that the application has no security and is a requirement to run it without connectivity.

Any idea about how to implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: Tell your customer that this approach is against any application design principles from either Google, Apple or Microsoft or any other vendor. You don't close the app for your users w/out notifying them, or at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I mentioned in the comments above, this is a really bad user experience. You should tell your customer you just don't do something like this to your users. never.

If I understand you correctly, the application is running offline, meaning it does not connect to the Worklight Server...

So you should probably just maintain some counter... if the user does any action in the application (touch a button, whatever), reset it. If no action was done and 10 minutes have passed, called [WL.App.close](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_closing_an_app.html).

Please note that using `WL.App.close` in such a manner in iOS can make your application be rejected from the App Store if found.

Comment: The real use case is to logout the user, I didn't wanted to say logout before to be clear that the application could be offline and the use case should cover that the application is running in offline mode.